# android recyclerview load more item upon scrolling using volley

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Please help me out to load more data from the server upon scrolling my `RecyclerView` . Here I have successfully created `RecyclerView` by loading data from my `Mysql` server by using volley string request.

**Here is my code.**

```
    private void populateRecycleView() {
    if (Utility.checkNetworkConnection(this)) {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Searching...");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Searching for the blood donor. Please wait a moment.");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.GET_DONORS_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            int count = 0;
                            while (count < jsonArray.length()) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);

                                String firstName = jsonObject.getString("fName");
                                String secondName = jsonObject.getString("sName");
                                String email = jsonObject.getString("emailid");
                                String password = jsonObject.getString("pass");
                                String mobile = jsonObject.getString("mobile");
                                String bloodRt = jsonObject.getString("blood");
                                String age = jsonObject.getString("age");
                                String gender = jsonObject.getString("gender");
                                String country = jsonObject.getString("country");
                                String location = jsonObject.getString("location");
                                String latitude = jsonObject.getString("latitude");
                                String longitude = jsonObject.getString("longitude");
                                String profilePicFIleName = jsonObject.getString("picname");
                                String profilePicURL = jsonObject.getString("pic");

                                Donor donor = new Donor(firstName, secondName, email, password, mobile, bloodRt, age, gender,
                                        country, location, latitude, longitude, profilePicFIleName, profilePicURL);
                                donorsList.add(donor);
                                count++;
                            }
                            donorsAdapter = new DonorsAdapter(FindDonorResult.this, donorsList);
                            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_search_result_donor);
                            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(FindDonorResult.this));
                            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(donorsAdapter);

                            donorsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(FindDonorResult.this, "Active data network is not available.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("bloodGroup", bloodGroup);
                return params;
            }
        };
        NetworkRequestSingleTon.getOurInstance(this).addToRequestQue(stringRequest);
    } else {
        Utility.checkNetworkConnectionFound(this);
    }
}
```

**And this is my `RecyclerView`  adapter...**

```
public class DonorsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DonorsAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Donor> donorList;
private String bloodGroup;



public DonorsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Donor> donorList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.donorList = donorList;
}


@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv_blood_donors_result,
            parent, false);
    return new CustomViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final Donor donor = donorList.get(position);
    String displayName = donor.getFirstName() + " " + donor.getSecondName();
    holder.tvDisplayName.setText(displayName);
    holder.tvEmailID.setText(donor.getEmail());

    String userProfileURL = donor.getProfilePicURL();
    if (!userProfileURL.equals("")) {
        Picasso.with(context).load(userProfileURL).resize(80, 80).centerCrop().
                into(holder.ivProfilePic);
    } else {
        holder.ivProfilePic.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_person_white_24dp);
    }

    bloodGroup = donor.getBloodGroup();
    if (bloodGroup.equals("A+"))
        holder.ivBloodTypeDisplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.a_);
    else if (bloodGroup.equals("A-"))
        holder.ivBloodTypeDisplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.a_negative);
    else if (bloodGroup.equals("B+"))
        holder.ivBloodTypeDisplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.b_positive);
    else if (bloodGroup.equals("B-"))
        holder.ivBloodTypeDisplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.b_negative);
    else if (bloodGroup.equals("O+"))
        holder.ivBloodTypeDisplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.o_positive);
    else if (bloodGroup.equals("O-"))
        holder.ivBloodTypeDisplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.o_negative);
    else if (bloodGroup.equals("AB+"))
        holder.ivBloodTypeDisplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ab_positive);
    else if (bloodGroup.equals("AB-"))
        holder.ivBloodTypeDisplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ab_negative);

    if(Utility.isNetworkEnabled){
        holder.constraintLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DisplayDonorDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("donor", donor);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Network not available.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(donorList != null){
        return donorList.size();
    }else {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView ivProfilePic, ivBloodTypeDisplay, ivArrow;
    TextView tvDisplayName;
    TextView tvEmailID;
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;


    public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ivProfilePic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.civ_user_profile_picture);
        ivBloodTypeDisplay = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.civ_user_blood_type_display);
        ivArrow = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.civ_arrow);
        tvDisplayName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvUserNameOnRV);
        tvEmailID = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmailDisplayOnRV);
        constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view_item_container);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: what is the problem??

Comment: please help me out to load more data upon the scroll. Now it's just like I have 1000 rows in my database and my recycle view generates its list by using it. This is a serious performance issue. So I need to load only first 50 items to my recycle view initially and after the end of this list I need to load another 50 items.

Comment: Where the data is came from is it from a live server or it is in memory data?

Comment: do one simple thing for first time fetch only 50 items from your database and then inside onScrollListner method of your recyclerView check lastVisibleChild position when it hits 50 then fetch the next 50 items from your db

Comment: Data is stored in MySQL db in an online server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I sort this out. I have got an awesome tutorial from this blog.

http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/06/endless-recyclerview-with-progress-bar.html.

I made some changes to populate the list because my data is on a remote server and by using volley library I fetched the data into the list. Remaining things are same.

Answer (score 0):

Populate your donorsAdapter only with the 50 first elements of your donorsList, create a function that save the position of the latest element displayed and add other 50 donors to your adapter starting from the latest position saved when you need it.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

First create an emptyList:

```
List<Donor> subElements = new ArrayList<>();
```

and pass it to your adapter:

```
donorsAdapter = new DonorsAdapter(FindDonorResult.this, subElements);
```

Now you can create a method like this (you can call in onClick event for example):

```
private int LAST_POSITION = 0;
private int DONORS_NUM_TOSHOW = 50;

public void showMoreDonors(){
    if(donarsList.size() > Last_postion+50){
        List<Donor> tempList = new ArrayList<Donor>(donorsList.subList(Last_postion,Last_postion+DONORS_NUM_TOSHOW));

        for(Donor a : tempList){
            subElements.add(a);
        }
        Last_postion += DONORS_NUM_TOSHOW;
        donorsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }else{
        List<Donor> tempList = new ArrayList<Donor>(donorsList.subList(Last_postion,donorsList.size()));
        for(Donor a : tempList){
            subElements.add(a);
        }
        donorsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Remember to check when donorsList is over.
I didn't test it, but i hope it is usefull to understand the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how it populates the list with another 50 items. Because my php script to fetch data from the server doesn't know the last item position.

Comment: Your donarsList contains all information that you need, you can give to donorsAdapter an other empty ArrayList. Now you need to iterate your donarsList from 0 to 50 and add one by one in your empty list. I'll try to give you an example, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Your effort is really amazing. Let me check this solution and update u. Once again thanks brother.

Comment: 0
down vote
unaccept
Finally, I sort this out. I have got an awesome tutorial from this blog.

http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/06/endless-recyclerview-with-progress-bar.html.

I made some changes to populate the list because my data is on a remote server and by using volley library I fetched the data into the list. Remaining things are same.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and concern.